# Gulp.js: "gulp-chug" only runs one file even when set to watching many

Tags: node.js, npm, task, gulp, watch

I've started working with Gulp and the problem I'm having is getting [**gulp-chug**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-chug) to work properly.

I've followed everything in the documentation, telling my gulpfile to watch all gulpfiles within certain directories, whereas it only watches one file.

This is the code I have used following the documentation...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var chug = require('gulp-chug');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('**/task_runner/gulpfile.js')
        .pipe(chug());
});
```

I even tried to see if it makes a difference if I put the filepath in an array...

```
...
    gulp.src(
        [ '**/task_runner/gulpfile.js' ]
    )
...
```

I also tried this (and a version without the array in gulp.src())...

```
...
    gulp.src(
        [ 'Project_01/task_runner/gulpfile.js', 'Project_02/task_runner/gulpfile.js' ]
    )
...
```

...and it still does the same thing.

My file structure looks like this,

```
*root*
    node_modules
    gulpfile.js
    package.json
    Project_01
        css
        scss
        task_runner
    Project_02
        css
        scss
        task_runner
```

All the gulpfiles work when running them individually, but I want them all to run at the same time within one **cmd** window with gulp-chug.

This is what my **cmd** looks like, which is showing that it's only watching Project_02,

```
C:\Users\WaheedJ\Desktop\UniServer\www\Practice\gulp>gulp
[14:19:40] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\UniServer\www\Practice\gulp\gulpfile.js
[14:19:40] Starting 'default'...
[14:19:40] Finished 'default' after 6.37 ms
[gulp-chug] File is a buffer. Need to write buffer to temp file...
[gulp-chug] Writing buffer to Project_02\task_runner\gulpfile.tmp.1411996780120.
js...
[gulp-chug] Spawning process C:\Users\WaheedJ\Desktop\UniServer\www\Practice\gul
p\Project_02\task_runner\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js with args C:\Users\Waheed
J\Desktop\UniServer\www\Practice\gulp\Project_02\task_runner\node_modules\gulp\b
in\gulp.js --gulpfile gulpfile.tmp.1411996780120.js default from directory C:\Us
ers\WaheedJ\Desktop\UniServer\www\Practice\gulp\Project_02\task_runner...
[gulp-chug](Project_02\task_runner\gulpfile.tmp.1411996780120.js) [14:19:42] Usi
ng gulpfile ~\Desktop\UniServer\www\Practice\gulp\Project_02\task_runner\gulpfil
e.tmp.1411996780120.js
[gulp-chug](Project_02\task_runner\gulpfile.tmp.1411996780120.js) [14:19:42] Sta
rting 'watch'...
[gulp-chug](Project_02\task_runner\gulpfile.tmp.1411996780120.js) [14:19:43] Fin
ished 'watch' after 18 ms
[14:19:43] Starting 'default'...
[14:19:43] Finished 'default' after 7.13 µs
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing happening. For now i employed this workaround :

```
gulp.task('default', ['one-gulpfile', 'another-gulpfile'], function () {});
gulp.task('one-gulpfile', function () { return gulp.src('./project-one/gulpfile.js').pipe(chug()); });
gulp.task('another-gulpfile', function () { return gulp.src('./project-another/gulpfile.js').pipe(chug()); });
```

Basically an empty default task, with dependencies on hard coded tasks that each, run one gulp file.

Of course not dynamic, and needs maintenance, but I got it going which is what i needed most at this point in time. I hope to see chug mature a bit more.